# GPG vs PGP keys - I am confused

Tags: pgp, openpgp

Is it a GPG key or a PGP key? Or do you just use gpg to produce the pgp key?

I see them used together, and its just a tad bit confusing. What do they stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the beginning (1991), there was PGP (= Pretty Good Privacy). It was an encryption software that could not be used outside the USA, due to export restrictions.

When the software finally became available internationally, it became a de-facto standard which later evolved into [RFC 2440](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2440) (and [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) subsequently).

GPG (= GNU Privacy Guard) implements said RFCs and as such, is able to use PGP keys.

Answer (score 2):

The standard is "PGP" and the key is called a PGP key.

GPG stands for GnuPG, which is Gnu's implementation of the Open PGP standard.

"GPG Key" and "PGP Key" are effectively the same thing.

Comment: So it it technically GPGP key? Gnu PGP?

Comment: @Akiva No, it's called either "GPG Key" or "PGP Key".  It's identically the same, the industry still calls them "PGP keys" for the most part.

Comment: @Akiva note that your question is a duplicate of another question that already exists and is answered and I've flagged your question accordingly.  Its answer is a lot more better than mine.

Comment: Sort of a duplicate. So what does PGP stand for?

Comment: @Akiva it IS a duplicate, 100% guarantee.  Read the other questino

Comment: Yep you are right. Thanks for taking the time to moderate. My apologies.